# Exact element position actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm having a little bit of trouble triying to draw a line on AS3.

Drawing is an easy part, but the tricky part is how to get the position of the component.

I'm trying to set a hierarchy, were the sons are conected to the father by lines. 
I have the structure and the components on the screen but when I try to draw a line between the nodes I can't find the position of the son.

```
    public function drawLines():void{
                for(var i:int=1; i<= _maxLevel ; i++){
                        var vGroup:*=treeLevel.getElementAt(i);
                        for(var j:int = 1; j<vGroup.numChildren ;j++){
                            var element:* = vGroup.getElementAt(j);
                            trace(element.fatherJoin);//a checkbox for the union
                            trace(element.sonJoin);//another checkbox for the union
                            var coord:* = buscarCoord(element.father,i-1);//with this function I get the father checkbox
                            coord.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFF0000, 1 );

//onwards is the fail code, I can't get the correct x and y to draw.
                            var pt:Point = new Point(element.fatherJoin.x,element.fatherJoin.y);
                            pt = this.localToGlobal(pt);
                            coord.graphics.lineTo(pt.x,pt.y);
                        }
                }
            }
```

The element is set on the vgroup via addElement and everywhere I look x=0 and y=0.

Anyone knows how to get the right coords. of this element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you need is:

```
// Create an empty point of (0,0).
var aPoint:Point = new Point;

// Get the global coordinates of the object you want.
aPoint = element.fatherJoin.localToGlobal(aPoint);

// Translate it to the coordinates of your canvas.
aPoint = coord.globalToLocal(aPoint);

// Now draw.
coord.graphics.lineTo(aPoint.x, aPoint.y);
```

Keep in mind that both **element.fatherJoin** and **coord** must be (not necessarily directly, they could be children of children) attached to stage, otherwise **localToGlobal** and **globalToLocal** will not produce the correct results.

UPD: I tried this.

```
var C:Sprite = new Sprite;
var Z:Sprite = new Sprite;

Z.x = 100;
Z.y = 200;

C.x = 300;
C.y = 400;

// Z is not attached to anything.
trace(Z.globalToLocal(new Point));
// output: (x=-100, y=-200)

C.addChild(Z);

// C is not attached to stage.
trace(Z.globalToLocal(new Point));
// output: (x=-400, y=-600)

addChild(C);

// C is attached to stage.
trace(Z.globalToLocal(new Point));
// output: (x=-400, y=-600)
```

Comment: I already thought of that, but localToGlobal, always get the same value (607,87) and when translated to global it gets (0,0). Yes both element and coord are children of children of children..(I think this is why I can't get the right position ). attached to stage. Thnx for your answer.

Comment: @Jaime I updated my post. The fact you are getting (0,0) in the process probably means your code executes **before** the components are initialized, properly placed and so on. Flex take like few frames from the app start before everything is created and placed correctly.